# About Minidlna and files list display

Tags: minidlna

I use minidlana on a raspberry pi3B from a few months and it works well.
On the TV screen when I browse my various directories, mainly audio and video, files are displayed not using filename.extension but using Tag.
Does it exist an option for minidlna.conf to choose what should be displayed or what is the solution to display filename?
Many Thanks for the help

Comment: As I don't get any feedback I conclude that no solution exist to display the list of components using filename.Many Thanks